# Need example for testing an asp.net web handler deployed on a server

Tags: asp.net, web, httphandler

I have modified asp.net web handler and deployed it on a server.

The handler works greate on my local machine using a static XML file but 
is giving IIS 500 errors when deployed.

Is there and example which I could use to modify my code to run against a 
live data feed ?

This is what I have used with the static file :

WebRequest req = null;
            WebResponse rsp = null;
            try
            {
                string uri = "https://mytestSite.com/Test_Handler.ashx";

```
            req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type


            // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());


            // Write the XML text into the stream
                            //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/20121129-0121-1.xml"));




            -- Would this line capture the stream ????????
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetRequestStream());




           string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
           reader.Close();


            writer.WriteLine(ret);
            writer.Close();


            // Send the data to the webserver
            rsp = req.GetResponse();         //Calls the handler code
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
            string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
```